# map/set iterators not incrementable error in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

When I execute the following code, I am getting map/set iterators not incrementable error.

```
typedef std::multimap<int, int> MapType;

assgnt::MapType my_map;
assgnt::MapType::iterator it;
for(it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); )
{
    my_map = obj1.addGoodNeighbours(it->first, it->second, my_map); 
    ++it;
}
```

Please help

Comment: Why do you not put `++it` directly into the for construct?

Comment: I tried that as well... getting the same error... while searching on google I found somewhere that ++it was taken out of for loop and it worked for them... but its not working for me.

Comment: We need to know what this `MapType` is. Apparently not a simple `std::map`?

Comment: For future reference, please state *exactly* what the error is. From your terse problem description, it sounded like you were getting a compiler error. But from your later comments, it sounds like you are getting a fairly specific run-time diagnostic error which would have been *very* helpful for everybody to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what a `assgnt::MapType` is, but assigning another `assgnt::MapType` to `my_map` inside the for loop, can't be a good thing:

```
my_map = obj1.addGoodNeighbours(it->first, it->second, my_map);
```

You should **at least** reassign the iterator:

```
for(it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it;) {
    my_map = obj1.addGoodNeighbours(it->first, it->second, my_map); 
    it = my_map.begin();
}
```

But i believe that code is far from correct. You are basically destroying the structure that you're iterating while iterating it.

**EDIT**: Well we do know what a MapType is now. All of the above is still correct. You can't just re-assign your maps while iterating them.

Comment: MapType is - typedef std::multimap<int, int> MapType;

Comment: assgnt is name of my class in which "typedef std::multimap<int, int> MapType;" is declared

Comment: Alright. We don't know what obj1.addGoodNeighbours does either.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying a map while you are iterating on it. This is not supported by `std` containers and as such is a bug in your program. Currently you are completely overwriting the object but more in details even adding elements is not supported.

You are getting this error probably because you are in debug mode and I would not be surprise if that would just crash in production.

To achieve the same effect you could use a temporary map:

```
assgnt::MapType my_map;
assgnt::MapType tmp;

for (auto it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it) {
     // you need to change addGoodNeighboors to add elements in place instead of creating a new map
     obj1.addGoodNeighbours(tmp, it->first, it->second, my_map);  
}

my_map.insert(begin(tmp), end(tmp));
```

Comment: You forgot an extra `+` inside your for loop. `+i`